# How to find records by a word it contains in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to filter my products.
I have 4 products in my Mongodb.

These are:

```
[
{name: "Dji Inspire 2", droneSeries: "inspire"},
{name: "Dji Phantom 4 Pro", droneSeries: "phantom"},
{name: "Dji Mavic 2 Pro", droneSeries: "mavic"},
{name: "Dji Spark", droneSeries: "spark"}
]
```

Also I have an input row (checkbox) for selecting drone series for which one to show you. These are Inspire, Phantom, Mavic, Spark.

When I check the inspire checkbox, I see the inspire drone. Everything is good until here. Here is the code which is finding inspire drones:

```
const droneSeriesArray = await req.body.droneSeriesArray //["inspire"]
const droneSeriesString = await droneSeriesArray.toString() //inspire
let products = await Products.find({droneSeries: droneSeriesString})
```

But when I check the phantom checkbox, the code is not working:

```
const droneSeriesArray = await req.body.droneSeriesArray //["inspire", "phantom"]
const droneSeriesString = await droneSeriesArray.toString() //inspire,phantom
let products = await Products.find({droneSeries: droneSeriesString})
```

I found something like this and tried it:

```
const droneSeriesArray = await req.body.droneSeriesArray //["inspire", "phantom"]
const droneSeriesString = await droneSeriesArray.toString() //inspire,phantom
let products = await Products.find({droneSeries: {$elemMatch: {droneSeriesString}}})
```

And this too is not working. So, what do you suppose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$in` like below

working [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mize0vGsSLK) here

```
await Products.find({droneSeries: {$in: droneSeriesArray}})
```

Comment: It works when I edit it like this: `Products.find({droneSeries: {$in: [droneSeriesArray[0]]}})`, It's not getting all array elements together.